# How to set ListBox item container to Card from Material Design

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, material-design, material-design-in-xaml

Is this possible to change ListBox item container from rectangle to Card from Material Design? This is code for ListBox:

```xml
<ListBox
    SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding  DateRanges}">

    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style
            TargetType="ListBoxItem"
            BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignListBoxItem}">
    
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger
                    Property="IsSelected"
                    Value="True">
                    <Setter
                        Property="Background"
                        Value="{StaticResource SecondaryHueMidBrush}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
    
            <Setter
                Property="Margin"
                Value="0 2 0 0" />
    
        </Style>
    
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate
            DataType="modelDate:DateRange">

            <TextBlock
                FontSize="14"
                Text="{Binding GetRange}"
                Margin="8 0 8 0" />

        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

</ListBox>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

And I want to have the ListBox with the same behavior but as a container, I want Card from MaterialDesign (rounded corners and shadow). When I use Card in `ItemTemplate` card is wrapped to content so I suppose I have to do this in `ItemContainerStyle` but I have no idea how. The final effect should look like this:

[image]

---

Edit: What I get so far:

```
<ListBox
    Padding="0 4 0 4"
    SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding  DateRanges}">

    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style
            TargetType="ListBoxItem">

            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiTrigger>

                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition
                            Property="IsSelected"
                            Value="True" />
                        <Condition
                            Property="IsMouseOver"
                            Value="True" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

                    <MultiTrigger.Setters>

                        <Setter
                            Property="Template">

                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate
                                    TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                    <materialDesign:Card
                                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                        ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}"
                                        UniformCornerRadius="8"
                                        Background="{StaticResource SecondaryHueDarkBrush}"
                                        ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplateSelector}" />

                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>

                        </Setter>

                    </MultiTrigger.Setters>

                </MultiTrigger>


                <MultiTrigger>

                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition
                            Property="IsSelected"
                            Value="True" />
                        <Condition
                            Property="IsMouseOver"
                            Value="False" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

                    <MultiTrigger.Setters>

                        <Setter
                            Property="Template">

                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate
                                    TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                    <materialDesign:Card
                                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                        ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}"
                                        UniformCornerRadius="8"
                                        Background="{StaticResource SecondaryHueMidBrush}"
                                        ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplateSelector}" />

                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>

                        </Setter>

                    </MultiTrigger.Setters>

                </MultiTrigger>


                <MultiTrigger>

                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition
                            Property="IsSelected"
                            Value="False" />
                        <Condition
                            Property="IsMouseOver"
                            Value="True" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

                    <MultiTrigger.Setters>

                        <Setter
                            Property="Template">

                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate
                                    TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                    <materialDesign:Card
                                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                        ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}"
                                        UniformCornerRadius="8"
                                        Background="{StaticResource mouse_over_color}"
                                        ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplateSelector}" />

                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>

                        </Setter>

                    </MultiTrigger.Setters>


                </MultiTrigger>


            </Style.Triggers>

            <Setter
                Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate
                        TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <materialDesign:Card
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                            ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}"
                            UniformCornerRadius="8"
                            ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplateSelector}" />

                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>


            <Setter
                Property="Margin"
                Value="8 4 8 4" />


        </Style>

    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style
            TargetType="ScrollBar"
            BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignScrollBarMinimal}" />
    </ListBox.Resources>


    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate
            DataType="modelDate:DateRange">

            <TextBlock
                FontSize="14"
                Text="{Binding GetRange}"
                Margin="8 8 8 8" />

        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

</ListBox>
```

In App resources:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="mouse_over_color" Color="#EEEEEE"/>
```

Result:

[image]

It is probably a bad solution, there is so much code, and also static color `mouse_over_color` is the same for the dark and light theme. Is there any possibility to add to separate colors with the same name to both Thames? Or any other way to make the background darker when the mouse is over Item? Something like an opposite to `Opacity`.

Comment: without reading all of it, i would have expected that you simply create a datatemplate for the item and put the card inside. the part with coloring the selected might be a bit tricky though. Maybe by having the color property bound to a viewModel. but then you would need a Viewmodel for each listbox item, which might be overkill. you could ask in the material design chat, but it may take 1+ days to get an answer: https://gitter.im/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit